# Java toUpperCase() and RegExp problem

Tags: java, regex

Ok I have a String that I'm parsing and I need to use toUpperCase() on that string.  After that I'm using Java RegExp.  Problem is that for some reason the Java's String toUpperCase() is modifying the white spaces and my RegExp will not work.

Is there a way to tell toUpperCase() to ignore white spaces?  Or maybe its possible to handle this in RegExp?

Below is the code I'm using to figure this out.  If I uncomment the toUpperCase() line below, my RegExp will not work!!

```
    String regExp = "([t][o][k][e][n][\\s]*[=][\\s]*)";
    String content = "The token ='testing'" ;

    //content = content.toUpperCase();  //uncomment this and RegExp will break!!!

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);

    if(matcher.find()){
        int startIndex= matcher.start(1);
        int endIndex = matcher.end(1);

        String posStartExpression = content.substring(startIndex,endIndex);
        System.out.println(posStartExpression);
    }
```

Comment: What in the world do you mean by “will break”? It does *not* change whitespace, because there is no whitespace codepoint that changes when uppercased. And why are you using square brackets all over the bloody place? Do you understand casefolding vs casemapping? You seem to be using one when you need the other. Have you first tested this out in an interactive language on the command line? If not, why not? What are your purported error messages?  What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encountering this behaviour because your regex is case sensitive.

Try this:

```
Pattern.compile(regExp, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: And what do you propose to address that way? Although there is a solution that uses what you wrote, you have to do more than that since their pattern is so screwed up.

Comment: I'm new to RegExp, so I don't know what I'm doing, but this solutions works for me!!!

Comment: Not sure what @tchrist is talking about: he said the regex works until he uppercases the input. I made the regex case-insensitive. It now works. What's confusing about that?

Comment: I think he may have meant that you should also advise the OP to improve the regex itself? e.g. something like "([t][o][k][e][n][\\s]*[=][\\s]*)" to "token[\\s]*=[\\s]*"?